# does thunderbolt support connecting multiple computers to a monitor

Tags: thunderbolt-display

I'm planning to get a new Mac mini server plus a mac book pro. 
I would like information about Thunderbolt support for connecting two computers to a single display, i.e. in my case the Mac mini to the Thunderbolt display port and simultaneously the Mac Book pro with the Thunderbolt cable.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean multiple inputs (like a TV)? In that case, no. The Thunderbolt display supports one input but allows you to chain additional displays or drives using the Thunderbolt port on the back of the display.

Answer (score 0):

Well it certainly won't work simultaneously. Your display can only read input from one source and there's no way to switch that unless you get a display that supports it. The device described [here](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/08/05/kanex-offers-switch-for-2-macs-1-cinema-display-with-snapx/) seems to do what you want, all you have to do is manually switch the input when you want to change. Honestly if I was in your case I would just keep the Macbook Pro hooked up to it and use VNC and/or ssh to login your server to administrate.